# select a column of data then a count of that column's value when a certain condition is true

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
project_id | created_by | created    
    1      |      3     | 2015-04-01    
    2      |      3     | 2015-04-07    
    3      |      4     | 2015-05-01    
    4      |      4     | 2015-05-02
```

and I want to select these columns, then a count of how many projects were created by the created_by before each project, to look like this:

```
project_id | created_by | created    | previous by created_by user    
    1      |     3      | 2015-04-01 |     0    
    2      |     3      | 2015-04-07 |     1    
    3      |     4      | 2015-05-01 |     0    
    4      |     4      | 2015-05-02 |     1
```

How do I select the count for that last column? I've tried count(case where [condition] then 1 else null end) but I keep only getting one row of results when I use that.

Comment: Use a subquery which selects the entries before the given with the created by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after ?

```
select
project_id,
created_by,
created,
rn as `previous by created_by user`
from(
 select
 project_id,
 created_by,
 created,
 @rn:=if(@prev_created_by = created_by,@rn+1,0) as rn,
 @prev_created_by := created_by
 from project,(select @rn:=0,@prev_created_by:=null)x
 order by created_by,created
)x;
```

Here is a test case

```
mysql> select * from project ;
+------------+------------+------------+
| project_id | created_by | created    |
+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 |          3 | 2015-04-01 |
|          2 |          3 | 2015-04-07 |
|          3 |          4 | 2015-05-01 |
|          4 |          4 | 2015-05-02 |
+------------+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The above query will have

```
+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| project_id | created_by | created    | previous by created_by user |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+
|          1 |          3 | 2015-04-01 |                           0 |
|          2 |          3 | 2015-04-07 |                           1 |
|          3 |          4 | 2015-05-01 |                           0 |
|          4 |          4 | 2015-05-02 |                           1 |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery which i already mentioned in the comments.

For Example the query could look like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
  (SELECT count(*) 
  FROM Table t2
  WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( t1.date)
  AND t2.created_by = t1.created_by) before
 FROM Table t1
```

It will return the columns of the the Table 'Table' and the result of the subquery as column 'before' which contains the count of before created rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.project_id  , t1.created_by, t1.created,count(t2.created) 
from t1 , (select created_by,created from t1) as t2 
Where t1.created_by=t2.created_by and t1.created>t2.created     
group by t1.project_id  ,t1.created_by, t1.created
```